# How to get position section and item from JSONArray?

Tags: java, android

Now, I want to create `Gridview` with section and I do following
[this](https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/e81e126227f8a4bb339c)

and then I stuck problem at I don't know how to get position section and item from `JSONArray`

I have `JSONArray` like this

```
“Team”: [
        {
          "team_id": "16",
          "team_name": "3",
          "team_max_player": "6",
          "team_amount": "2",
          "team_member_list": [
            {
              "id": "19",
              "room_id": "23",
              "user_id": "75",
              "team_id": "16",
              "detail_status": ""
            },
            {
              "id": "21",
              "room_id": "23",
              "user_id": "46",
              "team_id": "16",
              "detail_status": ""
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "team_id": "14",
          "team_name": "1",
          "team_max_player": "1",
          "team_amount": "1",
          "team_member_list": [
            {
              "id": "20",
              "room_id": "23",
              "user_id": "40",
              "team_id": "14",
              "detail_status": ""
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
```

I want to set "team_id" as section and "team_member_list" as an item in that section.
please teach me to do it.

I am currently in grade 12 in school with programing class, android studio, JAVA Moblie App. Please help me and sorry about my English.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: It's also unclear what you mean by "don't know how to get position section and item from JSONArray" - there's nothing about positions in your JSON data

Answer (score 1):

First you can load the JSON as a string and parse the JSON string using the [JSONObject class](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject).

You can then use the [JSONArray class](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray) to parse the JSON Array inside your JSONObject to retrieve the details you want.

See the code sample below that will log each team member's id along with the id of which team they belong to in the console.

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    JSONArray teams = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Team");
    for (int i = 0; i < teams.length(); i++) {
        String teamId = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Team").getJSONObject(i).getString("team_id");
        JSONArray teamMemberList = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Team").getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("team_member_list");
        for (int j = 0; j < teamMemberList.length(); j++) {
            String teamMemberId = teamMemberList.getJSONObject(j).getString("id");
            Log.i("team", "team id: " + teamId + " team member id: " + teamMemberId);
        }
    }
```

If you would like to learn more about JSON parsing in Android, I wrote a [JSON tutorial for Android](https://learntodroid.com/android-json-tutorial/) that goes into much greater detail.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to get the position of "team_id" to set Section in method
"sections.add(new SectionedGridRecyclerViewAdapter.Section( "position","team_name"));"
to create Gridview with section

Comment: Can you share the code relating to Section in your question?

Comment: I post my code below comment please help me to do it. I stuck on this page in my app too many days